# GETOPTS case with no optional arguments

Tags: bash

Hello I'm trying to find a way how to make getopts work with non of expected optional arguments

I have a script with optional arguments

```
script.sh [-a] [-b] [-c | -d] file
```

I have it working with -a..-d like this

```
while geopts abc:abd opt
do 
case $opt in
a) do this ;;
b) do this ;;
...
```

.. etc

I want to make it so it can work without those arguments, so I can run it like this

```
script.sh file
```

Is there a way to make a new case option or do I need to do it other way, thanks for all help, im a beginner in bash.

Comment: are you thinking of default actions for your shell script? (not a bad strategy in my book). you setup the default values before you process with getopts, and then any values passed in thru getopts override your default variables. Else you have to give us more detail about what your trying to acomplish. (Don't answer as a comment, add to your question above). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this kind of thing before:

```
declare -A have=([a]=false [b]=false [c]=false [d]=false)

while geopts :abcd opt; do 
    case $opt in
        a) have[a]=true ;;
        b) have[b]=true ;;
        c) have[c]=true ;;
        d) have[d]=true ;;
        ?) echo "illegal option: -$OPTARG"; exit 1;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if ${have[c]} && ${have[d]}; then 
    echo "cannot give both -c and -d"
    exit 1
fi

${have[a]} && do_a_stuff
${have[b]} && do_b_stuff
...
```

---

That case statement is a pretty egregious bit of cut'n'paste programming: tightening it up:

```
while geopts :abcd opt; do 
    case $opt in
        a|b|c|d) have[$opt]=true ;;
        ?) echo "illegal option: -$OPTARG"; exit 1;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the following test script:

```
#! /bin/bash

USAGE="test.sh [-a] [-b] [-c | -d ]"

while getopts :abcd option
do
    case $option in
        a) OPT_A=1;;
        b) OPT_B=1;;
        c) OPT_C=1;;
        d) OPT_D=1;;
        *)
            echo "$OPTARG is not a valid option."
            echo "$USAGE"
            exit 2;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [[ $OPT_C && $OPT_D ]]
then
    echo "That's a no-no using options c and d together"
    echo "$USAGE"
    exit 2
fi

echo "The following options were set"
[[ $OPT_A ]] && echo "    Option A was set"
[[ $OPT_B ]] && echo "    Option B was set"
[[ $OPT_C ]] && echo "    Option C was set"
[[ $OPT_D ]] && echo "    Option D was set"
echo "And the file name is $1"
```

It will show you what options were set (and which ones weren't). It tests to make sure that `-c` and `-d` aren't used together.

Not 100% sure what you're asking for. But, you can see that instead of saying *do this* in my `case` statement, I'm merely setting variables that show what options were or weren't selected. That in itself my solve your problem.